# How to create a table with a composite key made of 2 foreign keys referencing to other tables?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables A, B and funding:

1. Table `A` has a primary key `partner_id`
2. Table `B` has a primary key `branch_id`

When I try to create table C with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Funding (
    partner_id INT,
    branch_id INT,
    total_fund FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY (partners_id, branch_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (partners_id) REFERENCES A(partner_id) ON delete SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES B(branch_id) ON delete SET NULL
);
```

I get error message:

```
1830: column partner_id cannot be NOT NULL: needed in a foreign key constraint.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: **Bad** idea altogether.  Put a normal - independent of any other field - primary key.

Comment: PK columns can not be null. The FK ON delete SET NULL caused problems

Comment: Please read in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) what `ON DELETE SET NULL` means, and ask yourself, if that is really what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separted ID for PK:

**[SQL DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/85dmuYcKqUyHAwhbDSFUCg/1)**

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    partner_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (partner_id)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    branch_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (branch_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Funding (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    partner_id INT,
    branch_id  INT,
    total_fund FLOAT,    
    FOREIGN KEY (partner_id) REFERENCES A(partner_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES B(branch_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    );
```

You can also add:

```
ALTER TABLE `Funding` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(partner_id, branch_id);
```

But that can cause problem when multiple partners from same branch are deleted

Comment: A unique key on (partner_id, branch_id) should not cause any problems with multiple partners per branch, or vice versa; the uniqueness is on the combination, not on either.

Comment: @Uueerdo the problem is with `ON DELETE SET NULL` delete 2 partners and then you have two `(null, branch_id)`

Comment: Ah, yeah, my mistake, for some reason I read that last use of the word "deleted" in your answer completely wrong.

Comment: NULLs are not considered equal. So you can have values `(1, NULL), (1, NULL)` in a "unique key". If that makes any sense is another question.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza IMHO it's just as wierd as almost anything about NULL.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your inputs, very helpful. I just changed the "on delete set null " to " On delete set cascade " and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

In  CREATE TABLE Funding just add  NOT NULL statement to partner_id and branch_id.

```
CREATE TABLE Funding ( partner_id INT NOT NULL, branch_id INT NOT NULL,...
```

Comment: ...and remove `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Comment: The columns are already NOT NULL, since they are parts of the PK. NOT NULL is the source of the error, not the solution.